# Laravel 5: Get users between a range of age from date field

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm having a problem selecting the users between a range of age when the date of birth field in the database is a type **date** like 1989-09-20.

**Query**

```
DB::raw("*, ( 
        3959 * acos( 
        cos(radians(?)) 
        * cos(radians(latitude))
        * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(?)) 
        + sin(radians(?)) 
        * sin(radians(latitude)))
    ) AS distance"))
->having('distance', '<', $distance)
->orderBy("distance")
->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat])
->whereHas('user', function($q) {
    $q->whereBetween('date_of_birth',array(Input::get('age_from'),Input::get('age_to')))
      ->where('gender',Input::get('gender'))
      ->where('title','LIKE','%'.Input::get('title').'%');
})
->with('user')
->get();
```

I'm trying turning the **date_of_birth** attribute to a number of years using Carbon in the User model but is not working because is still taking in the query the date format and not the numbers of years.

**User model**

```
    <?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    public function getDateOfBirthAttribute()
    {
        $ca = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->attributes['date_of_birth']);

        return $ca->diffInYears();
    }

}
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution and is touse this wheteBetween.

```
$q->whereBetween(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,users.date_of_birth,CURDATE())'),array(Input::get('age_from'),Input::get('age_to')));
```